# Print a row of numbers and then have it make a new line and continue counting

Tags: python

I am wanting to print a row of numbers and then have it make a new line and continue counting.. ie calender..
right now i have

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                                                       
print(*numbers, sep='  ')


Sun Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat                      
  1  2    3   4    5    6   7
```

but now I need it to make a new line and continue.. any way I can do this easily?  My code is really bulky and cluttered if I write all of it out.

Comment: \n means newline in python and almost everywhere else

Comment: Yea but I am not sure where to add \n.. if I try to add it like such, I get an error.                                                 numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,\n 8];         
print(*numbers, sep='  ')

Comment: Did you try plain `print()`?  That will print a "blank line".  Hmm - on second thought, I don't understand what you want ;-)

Comment: Yes, I can type it all the way out using print();however, my code will be really long because I must do this for every month (including leap year).  I was not sure if there was a more efficient way of making a calendar that did not require a ton of lines of print(1, 2, 3, 4...31)

Comment: Also see `calendar.py` in the standard library.  There's an amazing amount of code there for such a simple thing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Python 2.*.** the following code will print numbers from 1 to 31, 7 in each row:

```
columns = 7
for i in range(1, 32):
 if i % columns != 0:
  print i,
 else:
  print i
```

Note print i,  and print i. Comma symbol suppresses newline character. When I want to start a new row I omit comma. Another way to start a new line is to print an empty string:

```
print ''
```

In **Python 3.*** print was changed into a function

```
print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```

or

```
print(x), # this will still print a space, but not a newline
```

The solution **including number [justification](http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html) bonus** would be:

```
for i in range(1, 32):
  if i%column != 0:
    print(str(i).rjust(3)),
  else:
    print(str(i).rjust(3))
```

Result:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
  8   9  10  11  12  13  14
 15  16  17  18  19  20  21
 22  23  24  25  26  27  28
 29  30  31
```

You may play with `str.ljust()`, `str.center()` functions to get justifications you want.

**Yet another way** to print numbers:

```
import sys    
sys.stdout.write(str(i))
```

The print() function also offers the sep parameter that lets one specify how individual items to be printed should be separated. That can give you an idea too.

Comment: is this for python 3.3.2? when I try to run this command, I get a syntax error for the i after both prints.  When I try to fix it with print(i), I get numbers in columns, not rows

Comment: thanks a ton!! I'm new to programming =/.. but thank you for your help! I got it now =)

Comment: wow.. terrible way to show you what it is doing.. let me try to edit this

Comment: I do not know how to directly show you what mine is doing, but I will try to explain.  My 1-7 is perfectly lined up under the days of the week.  But the further down(higher the number) my calender goes, the worse the spacing gets.  It gets so bad that 21 is not even under the last day of the week.  Any idea on how to separate one number or make it line up better?

Comment: I updated my answer and included code to justify numbers in columns. Have a look at Python 3 solution including justification bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '\n' to start a new row:
Python 2.7: print '\n'
Python 3.*: print('\n')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most familiar with python, but I can give you some psuedo-code.

```
int day = 1;

print("Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday");
while(day < DaysInMonth){

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i ++){

        print(day.ToString());
        print("  ");                    //spacing
        day++;
    }

print("\n");
}
```

Of course this solution is not very robust.  You have to progmattically determine DaysInMonth and this method will always have the first of the month on a sunday.